# how to update textview after text changed in edittext field

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, textview

I have this application where **field 1 is edittext** and **field 2 is textfield**. 
[image]

I want to add date into textview depending on the data entered in edittext field. That is after entering the data in edittext field and when i move to next edittext field the textview of 1st edittext field must be updated.
I know about add textchangedlistener but if it is the solution how am i supposed to implement it.

**EDIT :** I tried setonfocuschanged but it din work

```
k1_e.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View arg0, boolean arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if((v_k1>=5.63)&&(v_k1<=11.25)){
                k1_m.setText("mm");
            }else if((v_k1>=30)&&(v_k1<=60)){
                k1_m.setText("D");
            }

        }
    });
    k2_e.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if((v_k2>=5.63)&&(v_k2<=11.25)){
                k2_m.setText("mm");
            }else if((v_k2>=30)&&(v_k1<=60)){
                k2_m.setText("D");
            }
        }
    });
```

**edit 2 :**
and details here

```
dr=Float.parseFloat(dr_e.getText().toString());
    k1=Float.parseFloat(k1_e.getText().toString());
    k2=Float.parseFloat(k2_e.getText().toString());
    al=Float.parseFloat(al_e.getText().toString());
    al_const=Float.parseFloat(alconst_e.getText().toString());

    v_k1=Float.valueOf(k1);
    v_k2=Float.valueOf(k2);
```

**EDIT 3 :**
I get data into edittext fields using

```
if(dr_e.getText().toString().length()==0|k1_e.getText().toString().length()==0|k2_e.getText().toString().length()==0|al_e.getText().toString().length()==0|alconst_e.getText().toString().length()==0){
        flag=1;
    }else{

    dr=Float.parseFloat(dr_e.getText().toString());
    al=Float.parseFloat(al_e.getText().toString());
    al_const=Float.parseFloat(alconst_e.getText().toString());



    }
```

Comment: Add a `System.out.print("has focus=" + arg1)` to your `onFocusChange` methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this
  you can use onFocusChangeListener on youredittext

```
  k1_e.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

        public void onFocusChange(View arg0, boolean arg1) {
                       String data=k1_e.getText().toString().trim();
             if(data.length!=0)
              {
                      k1=Float.parseFloat(data);
                       v_k1=Float.valueOf(k1);
             if((v_k2>=5.63)&&(v_k2<=11.25)){
                                  k2_m.setText("mm");
                                }else if((v_k2>=30)&&(v_k1<=60)){
                           k2_m.setText("D");
                        }
        }
                 }
    });
```

Comment: @AhamBrahmaasmi What are those if conditions there inside onFocuschange? And what is v_k1

Comment: @AhamBrahmaasmi Get the value inside the onFocusChange..I'll edit to show

Comment: @AhamBrahmaasmi yes now you are on Track..I know the reason, I'll post

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27276/discussion-between-pragnani-and-ahambrahmaasmi)

Comment: @AhamBrahmaasmi Sorry my internet connection is too low so I can't enter into chat window..Ok..check my updated answer....

Comment: @AhamBrahmaasmi What happened.. enter into chat..What is the exception